# Is there a way to display a dataframe on debug console in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way for Data-frames to appear in a tabular format while debugging in the debug console.

I do not want to use Pycharm because it is resource heavy, so I am hoping Vscodium/vscode supports this feature.